# JButton won't show?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

So I'm looking at a tutorial here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/

At the very end, they show how to set an image as a background (which is simple). They use 2 codes: Board.java and Image.java (which I've copied below for your convenience).

For some reason, I can't seem to add a JButton to my GUI?

I tried adding the following code to **Image.java** after the line `Image Main = new Image();` , but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Normally I can just add a JButton to a JPanel using the `add` command and set the panel to visible with `setVisible(true)`.

```
    JButton start;
    start = new JButton("Click Me");
    Main.getContentPane().add(start);
```

I also tried adding a similar code to Board.java instead just to see if it'd work - and it of course didn't. How come my JButton won't show up? I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help?

---

(1) Board.java

```
package bardejov;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    Image bardejov;

    public Board() {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("bardejov.jpg"));
        bardejov = ii.getImage();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(bardejov, 10, 10, null); 
    }
}
```

(2) Image.java

```
package bardejov;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Image extends JFrame {

    public Image() {

        add(new Board());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(280, 240);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Bardejov");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image Main = new Image();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code above where you show us how you try to add the button to your current code.

Comment: Am I too tired, or am I not seeing the `JButton` inside the source code? ._.

Comment: Do you see the image? In your code there is not any JButton

Comment: Voting to close question. At least show what you've tried.

Comment: Of course I didn't add the JButton to the code above. I stated that in my problem? I'm asking *where* I'm supposed to put the Jbutton code. That's all my question is. I've explicitly said where I tried putting my JButton code...

Comment: @user2371809 Dude just put it where common sense tells you, and see if it works. Test Driven Development... kinda... I can guarantee that you'll come back here in 5 minutes with your problem solved by yourself.

Comment: Add it to the JPanel, or another JPanel. But at least show your attempts. One of the most important learning tools is to experiment with your code. Have at it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a JPanel with Board and Button laid out correctly. Then set this JPanel as the content pane for the JFrame. You are trying to add two different components to the Frame via different methods which is causing the confusion. If you resize the frame may be you will see the button you added in the background.